# How to map Spark Dataframe rows to a case class array?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
var df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq((1,"James"),(2,"Anna"))).toDF("id", "name")
```

My goal is to write it as a valid JSON output. But if I write this to JSON, I get a file with single JSON object on each line and it's not a valid JSON.

Therefore I would like a structure like this:

```
root
|-- Result: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
```

If I create a case class for a row:

```
case class ResultRow(id: String, name: String)
```

I can use it to map the initial dataframe to its objects.

Or if use `df.collect()`, I get an array of Rows. Then I can create an object of this class:

```
case class Result(var Result: Array[ResultRow])
```

And then I can loop over the collected Row objects, map them to ResultRow objects and add to the array in Result class instance. Then I can transform the object to a new dataframe and write it to JSON.

But the problem with this approach is that the `collect()` gathers all the data to the driver and when I have hundreds of thousands of rows, the runtime would take hours.

I want to get a dataframe with one column of Array type and one row with this array, which contains all rows of the initial dataframe as a single element and do it without using `collect()`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is you Spark version ?

Comment: the Spark JSON output is record-based b/c it can be processed again. If you need a file containing a single JSON object, you could easily wrap the output of Spark into a Json Array but we aware that Spark won't be able to read it anymore.

Comment: Also, making one huge row will have the same issues than `collect`: eventually, all data has to converge in one place only.

Comment: I think you need to re-think the approach. What do you want to achieve at the end? What needs to happen to the JSON file?

Comment: @mrsrinivas I am currently using Spark 1.6.2 on AWS EMR 4.8.3. But I was planning to move to the latest Spark version (currently 2.0.2) in the near future.

Comment: @maasg Well, I see your point about making a single huge row. I want to get statistics from my raw data. Basically the counts after aggregating the data. As we have a system which uses and displays statistics from our "hot" data source, this approach was taken to easily (un)marshal the statistics object. But the "hot" source would only have the data for the last month or so  So we needed to analyze the big data. I wanted for my Spark script to generate a JSON file exactly in the correct format needed for our API and front-end, just like our server does with the data from the "hot" source.